# Given a random positive integer n, what is the probability of picking a random positive integer m less than n?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, integers

Given a chosen $n \in Z$ where $n>0$, what is the probability of choosing a random $m \in Z$ where $0<m<n$?

The reason why I ask this is because my gut tells me it should be $0$ probability since there is an infinite amount of choices above $n$ but only a finite amount of choices between $0$ and $n$.

But this doesn’t sit well with me either, because well, what if you actually do end up choosing an $m<n$?

Comment: How do you choose a random integer? The distribution cannot be uniform.

Comment: You cannot do it in the way you think. What you can is to fix a maximum number $N$, compute the probability (which will depend on $N$), and then compute the limit letting $N$ go to infinity.

Comment: Ah so there is no uniform distribution among an infinite set of items? So does that mean it’s a badly formed question, or does that mean it’s an undefined probability?